# Exercise for implementing design patterns

Tags: design-patterns

I have started to study design patterns using some course in pluralsight and the gang of four book.
While I feel I understand what I have studied so far, I think it would be very helpful if I would have some way of practicing them.
I know that I will get the chance in time but I feel I would get a better understanding of each design pattern if I would do some exercises for each of them.

What I would like is if someone knows any websites or documents that provide exercises for implementing design patterns. I am particularly interested in ones where the author provides some source code and the problem that has to be solved and I have to implement a design pattern to solve it.

I am not interested in examples and theory; I already got that covered from what I am reading.

Comment: _"any websites or pdf that provide exercises"_ -- **[resource requests are not quite welcome at Programmers](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/tags/resource-questions/info "see respective meta tag and questions")**. As far as I understand, one would rather present an **underlying problem** instead - a problem that was intended to be solved with particular resource requested

Comment: I suggest [this programmers.se question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/49379/when-should-i-useand-not-usedesign-patterns) and [this one](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/157343/how-to-determine-whether-design-pattern-is-implemented-correctly).

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to try and un-ask the question a bit.

When I was studying design patterns, I got my practical experience by trying to identify where I was using the patterns already in my own code and where I might usefully adopt a pattern to improve it. Using programs/problems supplied by someone else would just not be anything like as engaging.

On the other hand, the tricky parts about patterns are actually learning when to *not* use them. It is this understanding of the forces and consequences that is the key to being good at using patterns, and it is genuinely hard. (The other bits of a pattern are usually pretty simple.) Patterns are meant to be a way of **thinking** about good road-tested software engineering approaches, and for **communicating** this to other people, but too many use them as a crutch or straitjacket, believing that they must use as many patterns as possible and that everything has to be done with patterns. That's utterly foolish.

I still recommend writing your own code, not using someone else's. You need some actual *ownership of the problem* in order to really grasp the forces and consequences, and those are the part that you need to really learn to think in terms of.

Answer (score 2):

The best exercise I can think is to to write a simple 2d game engine and something like tetris or pong on top of that.

Remember though, that it is important to know when not to use a patterns as well. Engineering just for the sake of it is not very cost effective.

Good luck!

(Incidentally, this interesting conversation is going on as well [When should I use, and not use, design patterns](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49379/when-should-i-useand-not-usedesign-patterns))